# WPF App， open window very slowly for the first time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've a WPF App. Windows Start-up, run it. after 'OnStartup' ,the MainWindow appears,then It's very slow to open A window. Opening B Window is fast. Open B before A, Opening B window is slow.

Why is there such a situation and how to solve it?

It's slow because `Window Show Method`,It takes about 5s,second, 0.5s.
This only happens when Windows is first started.
If i don't restart Windows, just restart the App, just 1s+ .

Comment: Did you test in any other PC?  what code you have in OnStartup.

Comment: Yes，the same as it

Comment: Provide us minimum reproducible code. How we could help without code

Comment: There are some data loading and initialization operations in OnStartup.

Comment: Comment it and try. data loading should be done on window loaded event to speed up your app start.

Comment: The data should be loaded async

Comment: Major time-consuming is `Show` Method,and Time-consuming tasks are async,

Comment: No they're not. They're blocking on the ui thread because your code doesn't do what you think it does. Otherwise there would be no 5 second wait.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a Method from another class inside my Start-Up.

My Solution was just to change the method to a static one.

This works, cause the StartUp wasnt forced to create a new Object of the Class( there was a lot of Stuff going on in the ctor).